# Why doesn't @Model... print data to index.cshtml but bring it to the view from a DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, razor-pages

I have a solution with 2 project

**1. Web Service**

**2. ASP.NET (MVC)**

In the view I have an input `type="date"` where I choose a date and through communication with the WS it has to search in a DB for the records that in their date column their data matches that date that I entered in the view.

**HomeController**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string date)//Get the date from the input type date
{
    SearchDate lst = new SearchDate();
    SearchDateResponse lstR = new SearchDateResponse();

    lst.StartDate = date;

    var r = await _servicio_api.Lista(lst.StartDate);
  
    lstR.factura = r;
    
    lst.lstR = lstR;

    return View(lst);
}
```

**SERVICIO_API e interfaz IServicio_API**

```
//Services ASP.NET Folder
    public async Task<List<Factura>> Lista(string date)//Receive the date from the "HomeController" controller var r = await _api_service.List(lst.StartDate);
            {
                List<Factura> facturaList = new List<Factura>();
                GetFacturaRequest req = new GetFacturaRequest();
                req.fecha = date;
    
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);        
    
                var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Factura", content);
    
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json_respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    List<Factura> resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Factura>>(json_respuesta);
                    facturaList.AddRange(resultado);
                }
                return facturaList;
            }



    public interface IServicio_API
    {
        Task<List<Factura>> Lista(string date);
    }
```

**FacturaController en el WS**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(GetFacturaRequest date)//Receives the date (date) from Service_API
    {
        return Ok(facturaService.Get(date));//Sends the date to the Get method of FacturaService
    }
```

**FactureServices.cs (Services ASP.NET Folder)**

```
 public IEnumerable<Factura> Get(GetFacturaRequest datos)//Receives the date from "api/Factura" in FacturaController.cs
        {
            return context.Facturas.Where(x => x.fechaEmision == DateTime.Parse(datos.fecha));
            //Find how many records in the database exist with the date entered in the input

        }
    }
    public interface IFactura
    {
        IEnumerable<Factura> Get(GetFacturaRequest datos);
    }
```

Then from here it returns to the if of the second piece of code that I uploaded, that is, this:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   var json_respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   List<Factura> resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Factura>>(json_respuesta);
   facturaList.AddRange(resultado);
}
return facturaList;
```

What it does here is that it evaluates if the request to the service was true, it returns the records if it found it or not. (If there are connection problems with the WS, the if is skipped and the execution ends)

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4spo.png)

And to finish, it returns to the beginning and returns the date that I entered and the records that it found with that date.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOs6w.png)

Then when I try to print in this case the date that the ViewModel brings to the view it seems as if it brought it but it is not shown, that is, in the following image it is seen that the date is in the @Model... in the label but when the execution finishes the data is not shown in the view.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUlL4.png)

In the end I try to do 2 things:

1. In the last image the date (StarDate) I want to print it in the view.
2. If it is possible `Count = 2` print it also since it has been the
   number of records that were found in the DB with that date.

**ViewModel in the view**

```
@model PORTAL.ViewModels.SearchDate //ViewModel
```

**Image of the view (HTML) where the data should appear.**

The **red line** is where the date should appear, to the right you can see the empty `<b></b>` and to the right of it another image of `<b></b>` but in the index.cshtml

The date should appear as the numbers 310/400 that are on the other label **(static data)**

[HTML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1It8Z.png)

Comment: If in your view you change `<b>@Model.StartDate</b>` with a hardcoded value `<b>2022-08-09</b>` does it show? Just to check if it's html problem.

Comment: Hello @Dimitris Maragkos, if I put a static data like this `<b>2022-08-09</b>`, it is displayed.

Comment: _"but when the execution finishes the data is not shown in the view"_ - and what does your rendered view look like? (HTML and/or screenshot)

Comment: Before finishing the execution I add an interruption point in the label and yes, if the data arrives as shown in the photo but once the execution is completely finished in the **HTML** you don't see anything at all, in fact yes I inspect the HTML I get like this: `<b></b>`.

Comment: Another thing, also for you to take into account in the file `index.cshtml` I make the call to a **ViewModel** from there I get the data but if that were a `List<>` I could iterate it with a `foreach` and yes, it does show me the data that way, but it's not what I'm looking for since I don't want to make a table or anything like that.

Comment: With that, it could be ruled out that it is an HTML problem, since if it were HTML, the iterated list with `foreach` in the same tag would not be displayed.

And well from there friend, we return to the main question, Why does @Model... not print data in the cshtml but it does bring it from the DB? u.u

Comment: @CodeCaster I had not fully understood your comment, there I added an image of the view and where the date should appear.

Comment: View the HTML source (press Ctrl+U), is it there? Is it possible that there's some JavaScript hiding the contents?

Comment: No, the date does not appear.

Comment: Weird. Create a [mre] without all the service stuff and the screenshot stuff and [edit] your question all over again. It looks to be a simple string property in a viewmodel, so this should just work. Are there any precompiled views, are you looking at the right view, are there partials or sections involved, and whatnot.

Comment: It's an AdminLTE view and the page never refreshes. I don't know if it's because of that (not updating the whole page), but I wouldn't like to have to refresh it since it's a small query, but I would like it to work like React, that is, it changes the state of the component in this case < b ></b> and as it receives data it updates the component, but I don't know if there is any way to do something like that here.